# How do I change the chat font in Skype 2.2.0.35?

Tags: 12.04, fonts, skype

Is there a way to change the font used by Skype for chat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install qtconfig. There is an option to change fonts. Don't remember to save changes.

Comment: Simply installing qtconfig and running it updated the font.